# Replace obsolete `Hashtable` collection

Tags: java

I have this simple ldap client which uses obsolete `Hashtable` collection.

```
class SAuth {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Hashtable env = new Hashtable(11);
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy/");

        // Authenticate as S. User and password "mysecret"
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=orcladmin");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");

        try {

            DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
            System.out.println(" i guess the connection is sucessfull :)");

        // Do something useful with ctx 
            // Close the context when we're done
            ctx.close();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Is there any modern collection which I can use without breaking the code instead of Hashtable?

Update:

```
class tSAuth {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<String, String>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy/");

        // Authenticate as S. User and password "mysecret"
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=orcladmin");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");

        try {

            DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext((Hashtable<?, ?>) env);
            System.out.println(" i guess the connection is sucessfull :)");

        // Do something useful with ctx 
            // Close the context when we're done
            ctx.close();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The only time you have to use legacy classes is when you have an API which requires it.  In this case you have to pass a Hashtable.

Comment: You could use a Properties object instead.  The Properties class is not considered obsolete.  Properties extends HashTable so it can be passed to the InitialDirContext constructor.  (Of course, this doesn't mean you're really avoiding the use of HashTable, but at least your code won't appear to directly use an obsolete class.)

Comment: It *isn't* obsolete, and you *can't* replace it, because it is part of the JNDI API.

Answer (score 2):

Use `HashMap` instead of `HashTable` like this:

```
Map env = new HashMap();
```

I'm not sure the exact type of `Context.*`, however, if it's `String`, then you could write the code like this:

```
Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

**EDIT:**

The [`InitialDirContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/directory/InitialDirContext.html#InitialDirContext%28java.util.Hashtable%29) constructor's parameter type is `Hashtable<?,?>`. So you should `Hashtable` in this case. Perhaps you can code like this:

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
```

Comment: Beware of side effects: `Hashtable` is synchronized by default, while `HashMap` isn't. If the code uses threads, it may be wise to use `Collections.synchronizedMap` to add synchronization.

Comment: Or something made for concurrency like [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

Comment: I updated the code but I use Object cast. How I can make the code clean without cast?

Comment: There is no InitialDirContext constructor that accepts a Map.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/directory/InitialDirContext.html#InitialDirContext%28java.util.Hashtable%29

Comment: So the only thing that I can do is casting object?

Comment: @PeterPenzov well, it would be better to use `Hashtable` in this case. Any special reason to avoid using `Hashtable`?

Comment: You cannot do a cast from a HashMap to Hashtable. It is perfectly ok to use the Hashtable here.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a Hashtable according to the java documentation for InitialDirContext.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/directory/InitialDirContext.html#InitialDirContext%28java.util.Hashtable%29

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [`java.util.Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) here, since it extends `java.util.Hashtable<Object,Object>`.